# How can I give arguments to time command (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, time

I want to get a bit more information than the standard time command gives, so I want to pass the verbose flag. `info time` gives as example `time -v sleep 4`, however when I execute that (both in bash or tcsh) I get

```
% time -v sleep 4
-v: Command not found.
0.000u 0.000s 0:00.00 0.0%  0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you execute `time` then (even though `which time` will claim otherwise...) you execute the `time` command of the shell. That version does not accept `-v`. Instead, execute the proper `time` executable: <sup>[[source]](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2005-April/033444.html)</sup>

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v sleep 4
```

That will work.